# How can i refresh and/or hide script content

Tags: javascript, html

Good evening! I have an assignment in school that requires me to:
Add a button that switches language from spanish to english.
And changing the DD:MM:YY Format, so i made a switch that changes them with each press of the button.
The problem is..... using this script...
'''
          
           var inicioTiempo=0;

```
       function fechaHora()
       {

        var cont=0;

        dt=new Date();
        var dia=["Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado"];
        var mes=["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"];
        var hora=["12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"];
        var fyh=" "+dia[dt.getDay()]+" ";

        switch (cont) {
         case 0:
           fyh=fyh+mes[dt.getMonth()]+" ";
           fyh=fyh+dt.getDate()+" ";
           fyh=fyh+dt.getFullYear();

           cont=cont+1;
           break;
         case 1:
           fyh=fyh+dt.getDate()+" ";
           fyh=fyh+mes[dt.getMonth()]+" ";
           fyh=fyh+dt.getFullYear();
           cont=cont+1;

           break;
         case 2:
           fyh=fyh+dt.getFullYear()+" ";
           fyh=fyh+mes[dt.getMonth()]+" ";
           fyh=fyh+dt.getDate();

           cont=cont+1;
           break;
         case 3:
           fyh=fyh+dt.getFullYear()+" ";
           fyh=fyh+dt.getDate()+" ";
           fyh=fyh+mes[dt.getMonth()];

           cont=0;
           break;
                                     }

        fyh=fyh+" <br> "+hora[dt.getHours()]+":"+dt.getMinutes()+":"+dt.getSeconds();
        if(dt.getHours()>=0 && dt.getHours()<=11)
            fyh=fyh+" a.m.";
        else
            fyh=fyh+" p.m. ";
        document.getElementById('labelFechaHora').innerHTML=fyh;
        setTimeout("fechaHora()",100);
       }
    </script>
<body  onLoad="fechaHora()" link="black" alink="black" vlink="black">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
    <center>
        <br>

        <font color="black"> <label id="labelFechaHora"/>   </font>  <br>
        <font color="black"> <label id="labelFechaHoraENG"/>   </font>  <br>

        <input type="button" value="Ingles" onclick="fechaHoraENG();">
        <input type="button" value="Español" onclick="fechaHora();">
```

'''

When i try to press once again the button, the script does not change at all, and the other one remains there.

1- Edit so that: Each time i press the spanish/eng, one shows up and hides the other.

2- When i re'press, the DD:MM:YY change (Asuming i had one function per language)

Comment: I think you had some problem at copying and pasting your code

Comment: Press `Ctrl + M` while editing your post to provide a reproducible example

Comment: Your `cont` would have to be at a higher level scope. It's being set back to `0` with every call to `fechaHora`. Also, I'm not sure why your doing `setTimeout("fechaHora()",100);` *(which could be setTimeout(fechaHora,100);)* at all.

Comment: Done! It should be at least readable.

Comment: I have 2 scripts, spanish and eng. Both show up when pressing the button, but when i press once again. Nothing happens.

Comment: @StackSlave What do you mean? Please can you explain to me in more detail? (I tried placing the counter outside the function, it switches indefinetly between the 4 DD:MM:YY)

Comment: The script shows, month, day, year. When the counter is sent outside of the function, it changes from, 0, 1, 2, 3 constantly, showing all the formats in one go, it keeps switching between the 4 formats, without stopping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of Object Oriented, mixed with Functional, Programming in JavaScript. I decided you didn't really want just an increment that is looped over time. Instead you want to be able to select a language and a format.

```js
function FechaHora(){
  let dt = new Date;
  const dia = ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'];
  const mes = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];
  this.updateDate = ()=>{
    dt = new Date;
    return this;
  }
  const formatIt = (format, array)=>{
    let m = array[dt.getMonth()], d = dt.getDate(), y = dt.getFullYear();
    switch(format.toLowerCase()){
      case 'mdy':
        return m+' '+d+' '+y;
      case 'dmy':
        return d+' '+m+' '+y;
      case 'ymd':
        return y+' '+m+' '+d;
      case 'ydm':
        return y+' '+d+' '+m;
    }
  }
  this.fechaDia = format=>{
    return formatIt(format, dia);
  }
  this.fechaMes = format=>{
    return formatIt(format, mes);
  }
  this.fechaTime = ()=>{
    let h = dt.getHours(), m = dt.getMinutes(), s = dt.getSeconds(), p = 'a.m.';
    if(h > 12){
      h -= 12; p = 'p.m.';
    }
    if(m < 10)m = '0'+m;
    if(s < 10)s = '0'+s;
    return h+':'+m+':'+s+' '+p;
  }
}
let doc, html, bod, I; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; html = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
const date = I('date'), time = I('time'), lang = I('lang'), format = I('format');
const fa = new FechaHora;
let ti;
function output(){
  let v = format.value;
  fa.updateDate();
  switch(lang.value){
    case 'dia':
      date.textContent = fa.fechaDia(v);
      break;
    case 'mes':
      date.textContent = fa.fechaMes(v);
      break;
  }
  time.textContent = fa.fechaTime();
}
function run(milliseconds = 1000){
  if(ti)clearInterval(ti);
  output(); ti = setInterval(output, milliseconds);
}
run();
lang.onchange = format.onchange = e=>{
  run();
}
}); // end load
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id='date'></div>
<div id='time'></div>
<select id='lang'>
  <option value='dia'>Dia</option>
  <option value='mes'>Mes</option>
</select>
<select id='format'>
  <option value='mdy'>M D Y</option>
  <option value='dmy'>D M Y</option>
  <option value='ymd'>Y M D</option>
  <option value='ydm'>Y D M</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am now editing the code, and testing out how can i implement the objects and the option selecter to my code.